# Implementing a simple bug tracking tool inside my SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, sharepoint-addin, issue-tracking

We have implemented a SharePoint 2013 web application , which contains two site collection; one community site & team site. Currently we have a custom software ready for testing . so I was thinking to create a simple issue tracking system , were users can report any bugs or changes and assign them to the development team. So what are the capabilities in SharePoint to support such a requirement ? the issue tracking basic fields should be; username, description, module, status, etc
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharePoint provides Out of the box **Issue Tracking** List template. You can use this list as a bug tracking system. You can add columns to the list based on your requirements. We have been using Issue Tracing list in SharePoint for one of our projects quite successfully.